# Cannot delete Microsoft account

Tags: microsoft-account, app-update

I am encountering a problem when trying to update WhatAspp. It keep asking me for my Microsoft account password, which I've forgotten. It went online trying to get me a new password but still no luck, and I can't update anything now. I'm thinking of deleting it and registering a new one but again can't find a way to delete the account in my phone's settings. Can you help me?